# D3 Sankey spread functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, sankey-diagram

I see some few examples of the D3 Sankey spread functionality being used [here](http://bl.ocks.org/wvengen/cab9b01816490edb7083). However, I don't see the function implemented in the D3 Sankey plugin.

Can anyone help with the Spread functionality code that I can inject in the actual plugin?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of [the lib layout they're using](https://github.com/q-m/d3.chart.sankey/blob/master/d3.chart.sankey.js) you can find the function.  If you just refactor and inject this it should give you a decent starting off point.

```
_spreadNodes: function(data) {
  var chart = this,
      nodesByBreadth = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.x; })
      .entries(data.nodes)
      .map(function(d) { return d.values; });

  nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes) {
    var i,
        node,
        sum = d3.sum(nodes, function(o) { return o.dy; }),
        padding = (chart.features.height - sum) / nodes.length,
        y0 = 0;
    nodes.sort(function(a, b) { return a.y - b.y; });
    for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
      node = nodes[i];
      node.y = y0;
      y0 += node.dy + padding;
    }
  });
}
```